# How to render all scene (Animation) using one blender file?

Tags: rendering, animation, video-sequence-editor

That are my scenes.
What I want to say is, by combining these scenes into a new scene in video editing, it will allow me to render these two scenes as a cohesive whole? How can I do that?

Comment: Look for tutorials on Blender's VSE (Video Sequence Editor). There are lots on YT.

Comment: Could you please provide me with a link to the video? I can't find on YouTube what I want to achieve. The videos I come across only focus on importing pre-made films and editing them or demonstrate adding individual scenes, but they don't explain how to render them.

Comment: I'm no expert on the VSE but you could try [this](https://youtu.be/pr6YlbELAuA) one.

Comment: Okay Thank you.